# Mesh Crumples at Elbow When Arm is Rotated

Tags: mesh, rigging, weight-painting, inverse-kinematics, forward-kinematics

When I rotate my characters arm so that both the upper and lower arm are facing down, the mesh at the arm moves around like it is crumpled.  I do not believe this is a problem with the weight paint, but rather something to do with the pole bone.  I think it must not be moving correctly with the bones to keep a consistent bone orientation.  What should I be looking at to fix this problem?

My current Rig is set up with an FK arm and an IK forearm.  The elbow pole is set behind the character lined up with the elbow.  The Pole is parented to the hand target bone, which is located at the end of the forearm bone. It's also a low-poly model which probably makes the crumpling worse.

Sorry, I am purposefully not showing my mesh because i wish to keep it anonymous.  I hope this is enough information to solve the problem.

Comment: hello, please show some screenshots or even share your file (delete some parts if necessary): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I am not sure about adding screenshots at this point.  I am looking at videos and stuff as well, but I'd like to ask you a question if nothing else:  does it make sense to have the elbow pole parented to the hand control - the target for the forearm ik?

Comment: sorry I've never tried that but maybe it works

Comment: I'm just not sure how the pole bone is causing it to deform so bad.  I think the pole bone is not supposed to be parented to anything, but I'm not sure what could be wrong.  The weight painting looks great.  Maybe roll?  Any thoughts?  Sorry about not showing the model :D If you can't help without it that's alright.

Comment: if you don't want to show the model because of copyright issues you can remove some parts of it before sharing

Comment: Oh wait!  I figured it out!  It was influenced by another bone which I didn't expect.  I should have checked but I thought for sure it wasn't influenced by anything else.  That's what happens when you think you know what you're doing lol.

Comment: I purposefully do not share my projects because if I end up using them in another account or displaying them publicly with my real name, I don't want this anonymous account to be connected to it.  That was my reason - although it may seem ridiculous and it is a pain :D

Comment: pasteall is anonymous. But anyway it looks like you've succeeded  ;)

Comment: Thx man for the help! (I'm just waiting for someone to move this convo to chat lol)

Comment: watcha think should I delete this question?  I'm guessing it will get closed for being a duplicate or something.

Comment: You don't have to care, the moderator will close if he thinks it's better

Comment: lol aight then cua